# SUM operation on attributes of children of multiple parent records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this method in my Product model that does what I need:

```
def self.available
  available = []
  Product.all.each do |product|
    if product.quantity > product.sales.sum(:quantity)
      available << product
    end
  end
  return available
end
```

But, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this, maybe with only one call to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you might try:

```
Product.where("products.quantity > Coalesce((select sum(s.quantity) from sales s where s.product_id = products.id), 0)")
```

Answer (score 0):

This creates a number of queries equal to the number of products you have due to the `sum` query. Here is a way I though of that will reduce database queries.

```
map = Sale.joins(:product)
  .group("products.id", "products.quantity").sum(:quantity).to_a
```

Which will produce an array similar to

```
[[[1,20],30], [[2,45], 20]]
```

this corresponds to `[[[product_id, product_quantity], sold_quantity ]]`

Now loop over this array and compare the values.

```
available = []
map.each do |item|
  if item[0][1] > item[1]
    available << item[0][0]
  end
end
```

Now that you have the `available` array populated, perform another query.

```
available = Product.where(id: available)
```

Now you got your same output in two queries instead of `Product.count (N)` number of queries. This solution can be inefficient sometimes but I will be updating it regularly if I had any ideas.